# What the ratio is between 1 unit in Three.js and 1 unit in Oimo.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Three.js of course has its own sizing system for when you create an object, but when combining Three.js with a physics system [oimo.js](https://lo-th.github.io/Oimo.js/index.html#planet), oimo has its own sizing system for the collision geometry, but oimo doesn't render anything on its own, so I'm confused as to how I'm supposed to figure out what the ratio is between 1 unit in Three.js and 1 unit in Oimo.js. Perhaps it's 1:1? I could try to calibrate it visually with trial and error, but there must be a better solution.

Comment: I guess oimo (whatever that is) will return the values in the same unit as they were passed in. Therefore if you pass in threejs units, you get threejs units back? However the docs of oimo are very poor, do you really want to work with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet they are both the same.. in that an Oimo box of size 1, is the same as a THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1). In terms of physics, I'd guess that in Oimo, 1 unit is 1 meter.